# Merging the predicted values to an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble with merging my predicted values to an existing dataframe. I currently have 2 dataframe one which has filenames and other dataframe with prediction values and both are of the same length . However when I try merging or concatenating I'm not getting a desired output.

Dataframe 1

```
    filename
0   1gBZ9vG1.txt
1   4XztkgDw.txt
2   GfCk8XGZ.txt
3   gfHCMnJM.txt
4   GfLCd17y.txt
5   gFqruhps.txt
6   gfsZpRDu.txt
7   gfT1yDbz.txt
8   GfT9mkJL.txt
9   GFTbJDLn.txt
10  gFwh0Ekb.txt
11  GGB7680Q.txt
12  R7NkR2q2.txt
13  tK2Xmi4C.txt
```

Dataframe 2

```
predictedLabels
0   2
1   2
2   2
3   1
4   2
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   1
9   1
10  1
11  0
12  2
13  2

Output
filename    predictedLabels
0   1gBZ9vG1.txt    NaN
1   4XztkgDw.txt    NaN
2   GfCk8XGZ.txt    NaN
3   gfHCMnJM.txt    NaN
4   GfLCd17y.txt    NaN
5   gFqruhps.txt    NaN
6   gfsZpRDu.txt    NaN
7   gfT1yDbz.txt    NaN
8   GfT9mkJL.txt    NaN
9   GFTbJDLn.txt    NaN
10  gFwh0Ekb.txt    NaN
11  GGB7680Q.txt    NaN
12  R7NkR2q2.txt    NaN
13  tK2Xmi4C.txt    NaN
0   NaN 2.0
1   NaN 2.0
2   NaN 2.0
3   NaN 1.0
4   NaN 2.0
5   NaN 2.0
6   NaN 2.0
7   NaN 2.0
8   NaN 1.0
9   NaN 1.0
10  NaN 1.0
11  NaN 0.0
12  NaN 2.0
13  NaN 2.0
```

I'm not sure why the labels appears below with NaN values though they are of the same length. I tried both merge and concat and also tried to reset my index but it does not work.

Comment: if you merge you need to specify the `left_index, right_index` args as `True` this will work `df1.join(df2)`

Comment: Thanks join seems to work

Comment: no problem, can you mark as duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
Dataframe1["predictedLabels"] = Dataframe2["predictedLabels"]
```